# MySQL Get non-processed SMSes

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using Gammu on my server to setup a SMS gateway, but I ran into a problem, when I was moving from receiving IDs to just get any non-processed SMS'es from Gammu's DB (in MySQL)
A bit of the inbox table looks like this

```
|     UDH      |       TextDecoded        | ID | Processed |
| 0500034A0201 | Some long text (156 l.)  |  1 |   false   |
| 0500034A0202 | Some continuing text     |  2 |   false   | 
|              | An SMS (less than 160 l) |  3 |   false   |
```

If an SMS is over 160 letters the SMS is splitted over multiple entries indicated by `UDH`.
The `UDH` is created by

1. part of the `UDH` (050003) indicates it is an SMS.
2. part of the `UDH` (4A02) is a unique identifier.
3. part of the `UDH` (01) is the part-number of the SMS.

I can check if the SMS is fully received, if the `TextDecoded` (of the last entry with the long SMS (with `UDH`)) is less than 156 letters long or `TheRecevingDateTime` is later than 3 minutes.

I need to create Stored Procedures to Get a SMS (here a SMS can be over 160 letters long) and Get All New SMSes (if the `Processed` is false). 
I have already created an example of how to Get a SMS, that looks like

```
DELIMITER €€
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetSMS`(IN smsid int(10))
   BEGIN
      DECLARE smsudh TEXT;
      SELECT `UDH` INTO smsudh FROM `inbox` WHERE `ID`=smsid;
      IF (STRCMP(smsudh, '') < 1) THEN
         SELECT * FROM `inbox` WHERE `ID`=smsid;
      ELSE
         SELECT * FROM `inbox` WHERE `UDH` LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(smsudh, (LENGTH(smsudh)-2)), "%") GROUP BY `ID` ORDER BY `UDH`;
      END IF;
   END €€
DELIMITER ;
```

But I can not figure out how to create a Stored Procedure to Get All New SMSes.

** EDIT **

- It should get all new SMSes
- A long SMS is received when the last entry (with `UDH`) is received later than 3 minutes due to `TheReceivingDateTime` or the `TextDecoded` is shorter than 156 letters
- An SMS without `UDH` is just received (it should not be combined with other SMSes without `UDH`)

I hope you understand my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM (
  SELECT
    MIN(id) as id,
    MIN(UDH) as udh,
    MIN(LENGTH(TextDecoded)) as txtlen,
    MAX(TheReceivingDateTime)-DATE_ADD(MIN(TheReceivingDateTime), INTERVAL 3 MINUTE) AS rcvtimeout
  FROM inbox
  WHERE
    Processed='false'
  GROUP BY
    IF(UDH='',id,SUBSTR(UDH,1,10))
  HAVING rcvtimeout>0
    OR udh=''
    OR txtlen<156
  ) AS baseview
ORDER BY id;
```

Since we can't filter by `where` for a time interval, we use it as a group function and filter by `having`

This will give back a list of id's, that you can run through your `GetSMS`

Comment: Thanks Eugen it was almost what I was searching for, but it is only showing one SMS without `UDH` (and in my Test-table I have 4). How can I fix that?

Comment: @The87Boy Fixed my SQL (GROUP BY clause)

Comment: It helped :D Thanks a lot. Can you tell me how to make a loop in a stored procedure. 
I have created your answer as a stored procedure, and for each ID I need to get the SMS and combine them. Or should I create a temporary table?

Comment: @The87Boy http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html starts with an excellent example: You open a cursor to my query from above, and in te loop you call your stored proc

Answer (score 0):

This statement should give you the desired output if I'm not misunderstanding the format, should be easy to put in a stored procedure.

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(UDH,7,4) uid, 
  Processed, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(TextDecoded ORDER BY SUBSTR(UDH,11,2) SEPARATOR '') text 
FROM SMS_table 
GROUP BY 
  SUBSTR(UDH,7,4) having processed<>1;
```

(processed is an int in this case, you may want to change the last condition based on column type in your schema)

Comment: It is not checking for SMSes that is not fully received and it combines single-smses to one item, but it gives some of the output I wished

Comment: @The87Boy Don't single SMSes have different unique identifiers? Can't see how they could combine if the identifier is different.

Comment: The unique identifier is the `ID`. The `UDH` is only set for SMSes longer than 160 letters